# Check if cxDateEdit is entered in the right format

Tags: delphi, devexpress

Maybe trivial but .... How do you check if the user has written the right date (in the right format) inside the cxDateEdit ? I know he can select a date with a mouse but just in case he tries to manually enter one, how can you correct his mistake if he/she writes a wrong date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cxDateEdit will not post an invalid date. If you have special requirements as what is a valid date then use the Properties.OnValidate event to reject a date you don't like by setting the Error var to true;

Answer (score 0):

> How do you check if the user has written the right date (in the right format) inside the `cxDateEdit`?

There's no need: providing a string which specifies a format for the `TcxDateEdit.Properties.EditFormat` property, the input must match the format.

See [System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime#Description](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime) for a list of the available specifiers.